# Spark with kafka: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I try to run java kafka consumer for spark and no matter what i do i get the exception. In the exception i see (ConsumerStrategy.scala:85) Why does it says scala here? does this mean that it it uses Scala methods instead of java? Are any of my libraries conflicting?

My pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

my code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName("kafkaTest");
       // sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");

        JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(
                sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka.kafka:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "spark_group1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
        kafkaParams.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "range");

        System.out.println("Hello1");
        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("spark");
        System.out.println("Hello2");
        ConsumerStrategy<String, String> cons = ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams);

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        streamingContext,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        cons);

        messages.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.printf("Mssg received {}", rdd);
        });
```

i ran it:

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar --class Main spark-kafka-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

(also withouti tried --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar
and version 2.4.5 of this lib)

and get the exception

```
Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$7.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$7.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
        at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I tried `export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10` 
also tried adding adding kafka-clients 0.10.2.1

still get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that there is another kafka library on spark.
/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar .
to overwrite it u used maven shade plugin. nothing else worked for me. see this link for details:
https://medium.com/@minyodev/relocating-classes-using-apache-maven-shade-plugin-6957a1a8666d